# Rmarkdown file knits to PDF successfully, but error when called from R

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, knitr, kable

I have written an Rmarkdown file that loads some data and generates a cool kableExtra table with some symbols and custom colors and lines, printing it to pdf.

It works great when I open the Rmarkdown file and knit, and produces the exact output that I want.

I would now like to use an R script that loops through some different subsets of the data, producing a new table (and separate output pdf) for each. So, I need to call my .Rmd file from within an .R file.

However, when I do this (using the `rmarkdown::render` function), I get errors that don't occur when knitted directly from within the .Rmd file.

Below is a fully functioning .Rmd file that is similar to the one I'm using with my real data. I'm calling it from a second R script, with the line `rmarkdown::render("table_creator.Rmd", pdf_document(latex_engine = "xelatex"))`.

The first error I encounter is `Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.`. I add `always_allow_html: yes` to the header of the .Rmd file and try again. Directly knitting the .Rmd file again works fine. Calling it from the .R script now yields the error:
 `! Undefined control sequence.
l.94 ...oup\fontsize{16}{18}\selectfont \textcolor
                                                  [HTML]{ffde71}{$\bullet$}\...`

At this point I think the rendering is happening with different settings of some sort than what are being used when I knit the .Rmd file directly. It's almost like it's not parsing the full header from the .Rmd file, but I'm not sure. I'm at a loss for how to proceed at this point and would appreciate any help.

````
---
title: ""
output:
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
header-includes:
- \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
- \setmainfont{Helvetica}
- \DeclareTextCommand{\nobreakspace}{TU}{\leavevmode\nobreak\ }
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, message = FALSE, warning = FALSE}
# Packages
suppressMessages(library(kableExtra))
suppressMessages(library(dplyr))

table_info <- data.frame(Symbol = c("$\\bullet$", "$\\blacksquare$",
                                    "$\\blacklozenge$", "x", "+", "$\\bullet$"),
                         Name = letters[1:6],
                         Results = sample(c("good", "bad"), 6, replace = TRUE),
                         FontSize = c(16, 10, 11, 16, 16, 18),
                         Color = c("#ffde71", "#0c0000", "#0c0000", "#0c0000",
                                   "#0c0000", "#cb6f86"))

 ktable <- table_info %>%
     mutate(Symbol = cell_spec(Symbol, color = Color, 
                              font_size = FontSize,
                              escape = FALSE,
                              format = "latex")) %>%
    select(-Color, -FontSize) %>%
    kable(escape = FALSE, align = c("l", "l", "l"),
          booktabs = TRUE) %>%
    row_spec(1:5, hline_after = TRUE) %>%
    row_spec(1:6, color = "gray") %>%
    column_spec(1, "1.5em")

```

```{r, echo=FALSE}
ktable
```
````

**EDIT: Additional context info**
Output of sessionInfo():

> sessionInfo()
>   R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
>   Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0 (64-bit)
>   Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.1
>
> Matrix products: default
>   BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
>   LAPACK: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libLAPACK.dylib
>
> locale:
>   [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
>
> attached base packages:
>   [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base
>
> other attached packages:
>   [1] bindrcpp_0.2     dplyr_0.7.4      kableExtra_0.9.0 rmarkdown_1.9
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
>    [1] Rcpp_0.12.15      rstudioapi_0.7    bindr_0.1         knitr_1.20        xml2_1.2.0
>    [6] magrittr_1.5      hms_0.4.2         rvest_0.3.2       munsell_0.4.3     viridisLite_0.3.0
>   [11] colorspace_1.3-2  R6_2.2.2          rlang_0.1.6       plyr_1.8.4        stringr_1.2.0
>   [16] httr_1.3.1        tools_3.4.3       htmltools_0.3.6   yaml_2.1.18       assertthat_0.2.0 
>   [21] rprojroot_1.3-2   digest_0.6.15     tibble_1.4.2      readr_1.1.1       glue_1.2.0
>   [26] evaluate_0.10.1   stringi_1.1.6     compiler_3.4.3    pillar_1.1.0      scales_0.5.0
>   [31] backports_1.1.2   pkgconfig_2.0.1

Comment: Can you post a `sessionInfo()` after you tried to convert the file from R? Can you past the generated `pandoc` command lines for the two cases? I also get a failure, but with a different error message.

Comment: Thanks Ralf. I added my sessionInfo() above. I'm not quite sure how to get the intermediate `pandoc` lines?

Comment: I got several messages, including a couple control sequence ones, that went away when I added some `usepackage` lines to `header-includes`.  I ended up adding `\usepackage{array}` `\usepackage{booktabs}` and `\usepackage{xcolor}` before the Rmd would render.

Comment: Adding the packages fixed it. Thank you much. I will know to check for more missing package declarations if I run into this again in the future. Appreciate the help!

Comment: As [I just said to another user the other day](https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/1368#issuecomment-396402560),  I strongly recommend you to put the content of `header-includes` in an external file, and include it via the `includes: in_header` option of `pdf_document`. The `header-includes` field in YAML could be fragile, so you'd better avoid using it if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I'm returning to this as I also had a very similar problem. The issue was that I was able to manually knit a PDF but once I did it via a script in R, I was receiving a `Error in xml_children(x)[[search]] : subscript out of bounds` error.

I was able to pinpoint that this was stemming from a `row_spec()` all within the `kable` production but upon removing the `row_spec()` call, I was then met with a `error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting latex output.` error.

The odd thing was that this only happened on a particular branch of my project - not the main branch. But, switching back to the main branch did not rectify the issue. Restarting R did. Further compounding the issue was that if I started R in the main branch and then switched to the development branch, but didn't re-source everything automatically, the error did not appear. This indicated that the error lied somewhere in the development branch's new scripts.

So I did a `sessionInfo()` call on loading R via the main branch and then the development branch and found that in one of my newer scripts, I had an additional `library(kableExtra)` that was being loaded after all the other packages were brought in (including a `kableExtra` call already). For some strange reason, this additional `kableExtra` call was also bringing in `virisdisLite` and `webshot`, two packages that were not originally present with the initial `kableExtra` call.

Once the extra `library(kableExtra)` was removed, the problem was solved and the two additional packages `virisdisLite` and `webshot` were no longer called and there were no longer any issues with `render()` to pdf.

Comment: Thanks for adding this info and solution.